# Adding paths to vscode python jedi from another vscode extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a vscode extension that includes python stub files for certain modules, that currently i need to pass to **python.autoComplete.extraPaths** manually, in order for it to hint/autocomplete.

Is there a way to provide vscode python certain paths from another available plugin, so that it can auto provide jedi autocomplete, if the two extensions are installed together.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension could set a person's `settings.json` for them, but otherwise there is no API in the extension for such a thing.